# How to ignore null values in C# Automapper

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I am using Automapper in C#.

Currently I am trying to map using below code.

```
CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.FeeType, opt =>
{
 opt.PreCondition(src => (src.Key == "Paid"));
 opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value);
});
```

I want to map only if the key == Paid else it should not map. However in this case , it is just passing null.

So lets say if the collection has 100 records and only 1 matches the condition other 99 records are passed as NULL.

Edit -- I am using Azure Function Apps and my Automapper version is 10.0.0

Please advise.

Comment: The answer is for Automapper 6 , I am using 10. I tried 
      ForAllMaps((obj, cnfg) => cnfg.ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))); 
      But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update your `ConfigureServices` like=>

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {  
    // Auto Mapper Configurations  
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc => {  
        mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());  
    });  
    IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();  
    services.AddSingleton(mapper); 
    //This line should be updated
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore);  
}
```

`.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore);` of`Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore`, It will handle what you ask for.

**Note:** Please check the link of a documentation. I believe it will do the trick. 
[LINK](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-ignore-null-values-in-automapper/)

Comment: Sorry , I didn't mention it before  , but I am using Azure Function apps. I was looking for something that I can configure in my Automapper profile itself if possible.